# Names in Alphabetical order then location in alphabetical order "Order By" not working

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am super confused. I thought I was putting the associates names in ascending order and then having my locations as a sub category ascending order. But even my associate names are not remaining in alphabetical order.

```
<cfset date1 = CREATEODBCDATETIME(form.StartDate & '00:00:00')>
<cfset date2 = CREATEODBCDATETIME(form.EndDate & '23:59:59')>

<cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetEmployeeInfo">
    SELECT  trans_location, date, associate
    FROM    cl_checklists
    WHERE   date >=  <cfqueryparam value="#date1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
            AND date <= <cfqueryparam value="#date2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
            AND trans_location IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.location#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  )
            AND associate IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.EmployeeName#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  )
</cfquery>

<cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetLocationInfo">
    SELECT  trans_location, date, associate
    FROM    cl_checklists
    WHERE   date >=  <cfqueryparam value="#date1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
            AND date <= <cfqueryparam value="#date2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
            AND trans_location IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.location#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  )
</cfquery>

 <cffunction name="getop_id" access="public" returntype="string"> 
    <cfargument name="associate"  > 
    <cfquery name="spitOutop_id" datasource="#application.userinfo_dsn#"> 
        SELECT assoc_name 
        FROM dbo.tco_associates 
        WHERE assoc_id= #arguments.associate# 
    </cfquery> 
    <cfreturn spitOutop_id.assoc_name > 
 </cffunction> 

 <cfquery name="allAssociatesQry" dbtype="query">
    SELECT DISTINCT associate, COUNT(*) AS associateCount FROM GetEmployeeInfo GROUP BY associate ORDER BY associate 
 </cfquery>

<table border="1" id="Checklist_Stats">
    <thead>
        <th><strong>Associate Name</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Location</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Checklists Generated by Associate</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Checklists Generated by Selected Location(s)</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Associate Percentage of Location Total</strong></th>   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!--- aggregate variables --->
      <cfset aggrAssociateChecklist = 0>
      <cfset aggrLocationChecklist = 0>

      <cfloop query="allAssociatesQry">
          <!--- get Associate's name --->
          <cfset thisAssociateCode = trim(allAssociatesQry.associate)>
          <cfset thisAssociateName = getop_id(thisAssociateCode) />
          <!--- 1.1 get all trans_location code and total counts for the current Associate --->
          <cfquery name="allLocCodeForAssociateQry" dbtype="query">
              SELECT trans_location,count(trans_location) AS locCntr FROM GetEmployeeInfo WHERE associate='#thisAssociateCode#' GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location
          </cfquery>
          <!--- 1.2 get the aggregate of checklist count generated by the current Associate for each location --->
          <cfquery name="qTotalChecklistCountForAssociate" dbtype="query">
              SELECT SUM(locCntr) AS totalAssocChecklist FROM allLocCodeForAssociateQry 
          </cfquery>

          <!--- 2.1 get the total location checklist for each location available for the current Associate --->
          <cfquery name="allLocChecklistForAssociateQry" dbtype="query">
              SELECT trans_location,count(trans_location) AS totalLocCount FROM GetLocationInfo WHERE trans_location IN (#QuotedValueList(allLocCodeForAssociateQry.trans_location)#) GROUP BY trans_location ORDER BY trans_location
          </cfquery>
          <!--- 2.2 get the aggregate of location checklist generated by the current Associate --->
          <cfquery name="qTotalLocChecklistForAssociate" dbtype="query">
              SELECT SUM(totalLocCount) AS totalLocChecklist FROM allLocChecklistForAssociateQry
          </cfquery>
          <!--- display record for the current Associate --->
            <cfoutput query="allLocCodeForAssociateQry">
              <tr>
                  <!---<td><strong>#thisAssociateCode#</strong></td>--->
                  <td><strong>#thisAssociateName#</strong></td>
                  <td>#allLocCodeForAssociateQry.trans_location#</td>
                  <td>#allLocCodeForAssociateQry.locCntr#</td>
                  <td>#allLocChecklistForAssociateQry['totalLocCount'][CurrentRow]#</td>
                  <td>#NumberFormat((allLocCodeForAssociateQry.locCntr/allLocChecklistForAssociateQry['totalLocCount'][CurrentRow]) * 100, '9.99')#%</td>
              </tr>
              <cfset thisAssociateName = "" />
            </cfoutput>
            <!--- 3.1 get sub total for each Associate group --->
            <cfset totalAssocChecklist = qTotalChecklistCountForAssociate.totalAssocChecklist>
            <cfset totalLocChecklist = qTotalLocChecklistForAssociate.totalLocChecklist>
            <!--- 3.2 add to the aggregate --->
            <cfset aggrAssociateChecklist += totalAssocChecklist>
            <cfset aggrLocationChecklist += totalLocChecklist>
            <!--- display sub total for each Associate group --->
            <cfoutput>
                <tr>
                    <td>Associate Total</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>#totalAssocChecklist#</td>
                    <td>#totalLocChecklist#</td>
                    <td>#NumberFormat((totalAssocChecklist/totalLocChecklist) * 100, '9.99')#%</td>
                </tr>
            </cfoutput>
      </cfloop>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Will someone please tell me why this is not listing the associates names in alphabetical order and then the locations in order once the associate names are in order?

I thought `ORDER BY associate` was doing it but the names are completely scattered. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems more complicated than it needs to be.  Plus, you might have more queries than you really need.

Comment: I would suggest you delete most of your code and make a very small sample. Do I understand right: the line `<td><strong>#thisAssociateName#</strong></td>` gives your associates in the wrong order?

Comment: Combine those queries, or rather the data you need from those queries. You are beating up your app server, and you can get the information you need in a single pass from the database itself. Trim your associate names before you return them from the database. You may have some with leading spaces, which will bork your first ORDER BY.

Comment: What type of SQL?

Comment: @DavidBrierton What is the query for GetLocationInfo? Your cfquery says it is a query of query, but I don't see the  query it's supposed to come from. Also, what does getop_id() do? Is this also something that can be pulled from a database table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151402/discussion-between-shawn-and-david-brierton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you the Associates in the order you want.

```
<cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="GetEmployeeInfo">
    SELECT ltrim(rtrim(c.associate)) AS thisAssociateCode  --<< GetEmployeeInfo
        , a.assoc_name AS thisAssociateName --<< getop_id.assoc_name
        , c.trans_location --<< GetEmployeeInfo
        , c.[date] --<< GetEmployeeInfo
    FROM    cl_checklists c
    INNER JOIN dbo.tco_associates a ON c.associate = a.assoc_id
    WHERE   c.[date] >=  <cfqueryparam value="#date1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
            AND c.[date] <= <cfqueryparam value="#date2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
            AND c.trans_location IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.location#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  )
            AND c.associate IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.EmployeeName#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />  )
    ORDER BY a.assoc_name
</cfquery>
```

It will also allow you to remove the getop_id function.

And you can get rid of:

```
<cfset thisAssociateCode = trim(allAssociatesQry.associate)>
<cfset thisAssociateName = getop_id(thisAssociateCode) />
```

Comment: Do you have data that returns with the filters? Just `SELECT` from cl_checklists for the date range and the location and associate. Somewhere it's removing rows from the query.

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of that one for you. This query should ultimately replace the `allassociatesqry`. Does `tco_associates` JOIN to `cl_checklists` ON associate = assoc_id?

Comment: You _should_ be able to knock this down to 1 or maybe 2 database calls. I'm still looking at it.

Comment: Do you have a definition handy of what the totals are supposed to be? I've got a query that grabs all the numbers, but I don't think it's summing them correctly. If I can get this down to the one query, you shouldn't need to reference CurrentRow in any of the output. Just a simple loop through the results.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:**

It looks like the `allAssociatesQry` query is ordering by associate *code*, not associate name:

`SELECT DISTINCT associate, COUNT(*) AS associateCount FROM GetEmployeeInfo GROUP BY associate ORDER BY associate`

Since you then do:

```
<cfset thisAssociateCode = trim(allAssociatesQry.associate)>
```

It seems that associate codes aren't necessarily in name order?

**Proposed solution:**

Change `allAssociatesQry` to `JOIN` with `tco_associates` and then `ORDER BY` the associate name:

`SELECT DISTINCT gei.associate, a.assoc_name, COUNT(*) AS associateCount FROM GetEmployeeInfo gei JOIN tco_associates a ON gei.associate = a.assoc_id GROUP BY gei.associate, a.assoc_name ORDER BY a.associateName`

Comment: From what you've posted I'd still stand by the gist of this answer, although the solution needs to be tweaked a bit. Does `cl_checklists` have an `assoc_id` field?

Comment: Have updated the proposed solution following your edit.

Comment: Would be a bit cautious about doing a `LEFT JOIN` since it looks like the only field in `cl_checklists` you'd be able to join on is the associate name - am guessing this isn't guaranteed to be unique and probably isn't indexed?

Comment: OK that's a fair point, was thinking you meant a join in `cl_checklists` but actually a join in `allAssociatesQry` instead should make it much simpler. Have updated the answer.